# AngularJS: ng-controller multiple functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS to show and retreive data from my users in HTML like:

```
   <table id="app2" ng-app="categories" ng-cloak="" class="table table-hover" style="margin-top: 50px;">
     <tr style="background-color:#4d748f; color:white;">
      <th colspan="5" style="text-align:center; font-size:16px;">Add category</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <form novalidate>
      <td colspan="4">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Category name"></input>
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"></input>
      </td>                                    
     </form>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#4d748f; color:white;">
     <th colspan="5" style="text-align:center; font-size:16px;">Add product</th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <form ng-controller="category">
      <td colspan="1">
       <select class="form-control m-b-10">
       <option ng-repeat= "c in categories">{{c[1]}}</option>
       </select>
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
      <select class="form-control m-b-10">
        <option>Antwerpen</option>
        <option>Leuven</option>
      </select> 
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"></input>
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" width="10%"></input>
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="product()"></input>
      </td>                                    
     </form>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

**ANGULARJS**

```
categories = angular.module('categories', []);
categories.controller("category",function($scope, $http){
    var serviceBase = 'api/';
    $http.get(serviceBase + 'categories').then(function (results) {
        $scope.categories = results.data;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.categories.length; i++){
            var categories = $scope.categories[i];
        }
        $scope.product = function($scope, $http){
        $http.post(serviceBase + 'productadd/'+$scope.catID+'/'+$scope.catID+'/'+$scope.pname+'/'+$scope.pprice).then(function(results){
            alert('ok');
        });
        }
    });
});
```

When I place my ng-controller on the select item to get the ng-repeat = c in categories. Then this works and I get the categories shown in my dropdown. But when I place it on the form tag it doesn't... I have to place it on my form tag because I want to add a product into my database after the user clicks the button to add products. And ng-click=product() gets called.

How can both of those functions function together?

Comment: Your markup is wrong. You can not wrap form element around tr tag.

Comment: @kalpeshpatel  Too broad: You don't know the DOCTYPE. So if its XML/XHTML its valide.

Comment: @lin, I agree with you for this. Thanks for pointing it though. I was referring to HTML5 doctype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot wrap `tr` with you custom element except `tbody`, `thead`, `table`.. Simply used `ng-form` directive on `tr` which can be used as attribute

```
 <tr ng-form name="myform" novalidate>
    <td colspan="4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Category name"></input>
    </td>
    <td colspan="1">
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"></input>
     </td>                                    
 </tr>
```